# How to get the MaterialAlertDialog currents background color

Tags: android, material-design

I have **two overlayed** views on my MaterialAlertDialog for swiping.
If the users swipes you see the lower view.

So I need to set the same background color for the top view as the background of the MaterialAlertDialog.
How can I get the **background color** of the current MaterialAlertDialog?

Using for my dark theme this style:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert
```

And for the light theme this style:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert
```

Main Theme parent is also Material with light and dark:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
```

Have already tried `?android:attr/background` but this is not the same color as the background of the Material Alert Dialog :-(

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you can use the style to set alerDialog. the code like the following:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
</style>

val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme))
```

Secondly, if you want to konw the defalut theme background color. see this [link](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/material-components/material-components-android/-/blob/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/themes.xml).
it is located in `lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values`

thirdly, you can use code to set the color.

```
alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground()
```

I suggest you set the custom theme

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know the AlertDialogTheme and I use it already but I don't find the attribute for the background color of the material alert dialog.

I tried the code but it would be better to use an attribute directly on the view.
Do you know the attribute which is used for the MaterialAlertDialogBackground?

Comment: @chrisonline, in the second solution, I give the source code. you can look up it. I find a `<item name="colorOnBackground">@color/design_dark_default_color_on_background</item>` attrs.

Comment: Tried that already and a lot of other attributes. They are not 100% the same color as the background :-(